# update products in pivot table that have three actions when updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

When updating an order I want to update the products I defined their id from pivot table and delete the ones I didn't update for this order, at the same time attach new products that *I didn't put id for them* ( cause they already don't exist ).

---

that's how my body looks like when creating an order

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "product_id": 1,
        "color": "red",
        "quantity": 2
    },
  
    {
        "product_id": 2,
        "color": "black",
        "quantity": 3
    }
]}
```

that's how my body looks like when updating an order

```
{
"products": [
          {
        "product_id": 2,
        "color": "red",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "product_id": 1,
        "color": "red",
        "quantity": 23
    },
    {
        "product_id": 1,
        "color": "black",
        "quantity": 8
    }

]}
```

that's what I expected to see in my pivot table

| id | product_id | order_id | color | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | red | 23 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | red | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | black | 8 |

instead, got this

| id | product_id | order_id | color | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | red | 23 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | black | 8 |

---

> OrderConroller

```php
public function update(AdminUpdateOrderRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $orderValidated = $request->validated();

        $order = Order::findOrFail($id);

        $order->update($orderValidated);

        foreach ($orderValidated['products'] as $p) {
            if (isset($p['id'])) {
                $order->products()->sync([
                    $p['product_id'] => [
                        'color' => $p['color'],
                        'quantity' => $p['quantity'],
                    ]
                ]);
            } else {
                $p['id'] = null;
                $order->products()->where(! isset($p['id']))->attach([
                    $p['product_id'] => [
                        'color' => $p['color'],
                        'quantity' => $p['quantity'],
                    ]
                ]);

            };

        return OrderResource::make($order)->additional([
            'success' => true,
        ]);
        }
```

> AdminUpdateOrderRequest

```php
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'products' => 'array',
            'products.*.id' => 'exists:order_product,id',
            'products.*.product_id' => 'exists:products,id',
            'products.*.color' => 'string',
            'products.*.quantity' => 'integer|min:1'
        ];
    }
```

---

I know there are a lot of logical errors here, so I need help.. Thank you.

Comment: In your expected table sample scenario, where does `order_id` of `2` come from?

Comment: sorry I meant order_id = 1 @Christian